# cAdvisor metrics are missing container label when pod label is defined

Tags: kubernetes, cadvisor

We use Victoria Metrics pipeline to monitor our kubernetes workload. Our job to scrape [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) metrics is a follows:

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes-cadvisor'

 kubernetes_sd_configs:

 - role: node

 scheme: https

 metrics_path: /metrics/cadvisor

 tls_config:

   ca_file: $SVC_CA_CERT_PATH

   insecure_skip_verify: true

 bearer_token_file: $SVC_TOKEN_FILE_PATH
```

We have defined multiple filters in grafana to be able to observe application performance in multiple environments and cluster from single dashboard.
So we rely on labels associated with `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` metrics to define our filter conditions. I am specifically interested in `container` and `pod` label.

Any idea why container label might be missing from `container_spec_cpu_shares` metrics?

Comment: You can check the raw Prometheus metrics scraped by Victoria Metrics for the container_spec_cpu_shares metric and see if they include the container label. You can do this by navigating to the Prometheus endpoint for your Victoria Metrics instance and running a query for the container_spec_cpu_shares metric. If the container label is not present in the raw metrics, then it was likely not included in the original metrics generated by cAdvisor.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Siddhpura. I did checked the raw metrics, the container label is sometimes present and sometimes its null. Another observation is whenever container label is not null, pod label is null.
My expectation was container pod label should always be preset and container label should give appropriate cpu shares. Is my expectations wrong?